# Process json object in spring controller

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I have this basic quiz app that I'm trying to build and right now I'm stuck on processing the submitted quiz answers in spring.

I use a js function to store the question id and submitted answers id's in a json object like so:

```
{
   1: [2,3,4],
   2: [1,2]
}
```

So, the user sent the answers 2,3,4 for the question with the id of 1. Now, I'm trying to send this json object to the spring controller method using ajax.

```
// DO POST
            function ajaxSubmitAns(formdata){
                $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    url : "/process-answers",
                    data: JSON.stringify(formData),
                    contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    headers: {
                          Accept: 'application/json'
                    },
                    success: function(){
                        //do something
                    },
                    error : function(e) {
                        //error
                    }
                });
            }
```

I also wrote the controller function but what I don't know is how do I access these values from the json object. How can I loop through the keys (questions id's) and get the values?

What I have for the controller is this so far:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/process-answers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public  @ResponseBody
String  processQuizz(@RequestBody String json) {

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@PostMapping("/process-answers")
@ResponseBody 
public void processQuizz(@RequestBody Map<Integer, List<Integer> quiz) {
   quiz.forEach((quizId, answers) -> ... your business logic here ...);
}
```

Now you can iterate through your map directly without json processing.